# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" with java configuration

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, taglib, apache-tiles

I am currently learning spring mvc and made an example "my app" which  includes spring mvc and apache tiles. Everything works fine but in jsp i get this following error:

Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"

here is my mainLayout.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title><tiles:getAsString name="title" /></title>
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/bootstrap.css' />"  rel="stylesheet"></link>
        <link href="<c:url value='/static/css/app.css' />" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    </head>

    <body>
            <header id="header">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            </header>


            <section id="site-content">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
            </section>

            <footer id="footer">
                <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

before you ask, I have included all the spring ,tiles and jstl dependency in my pom.
only the form tag gives error.

Comment: yes I saw that question but the solution doesn't work for me because.I did not use web.xml used java configuration.

Comment: You should explicitly describe that constraint in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your tag library is missing form the class-path
As You don't have to configure anything. Since JSP 2.0 taglibs can be discovered automatically.

All You need to do is place them in WEB-INF or it's sub-folders. If you are packaging Your TLDs as JAR files, place them in WEB-INF/lib or META-INF of the JAR

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i use maven for the libraries and I don't know how to place them in WEB-INF or its subfolders.

Comment: There must be a WEB-INF folder automatically created in your project

Comment: Try including this liberary and go to project->run->Maven Install